# Disable Jedi linting for Python in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jedi

I have set my linter for Python to Pylint, but I still get error messages from Jedi. I even went to settings.json and added the line `"python.linting.jediEnabled": false`, but the line, though present, is greyed out. What more can I do?

Comment: Just wondering: Why are the Jedi error messages annoying? They should pretty much only be syntax errors, right?

Comment: @themadpsychologist -What is the specific information from Jedi you want to close? In my test, Jedi did not show code problems by default in VS Code.

Comment: @DaveHalter First, they keep bugging me about a file in builtins that I didn't write. Second, they persistently warn me while I'm in the middle of typing a line that my code is incomplete because I'm still writing it. It wouldn't be so bad if it would warn me only on save. With Pylint, though, it seems redundant anyway.

Comment: @JillCheng If that were the case for me, it would solve my problem entirely. What changes to the default settings might have caused persistent Jedi linting that I can't disable?

Comment: @themadpsychologist -Is there any information displayed in the "PROBLEMS" of the VS Code? we need to judge its source based on specific information to close it, therefore, please provide us with relevant content or screenshots.

Comment: @JillCheng I am not asking for help with a specific error. I wish to disable Jedi linting in VS Code.

Comment: @JillCheng If it helps at all, the most common error I receive while coding is `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`, due to aforementioned continuous linting rather than linting on save. It goes away once I finish the line or block of code, but I would prefer never to see it in the first place; I save when I want to test.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to `settings.json` and add the line `"python.languageServer": "None"`. Then restart VSCode.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer removes all linting and intellisense-like features, rather than removing jedi per-se.

Note that [since this pull request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/pull/12226) Jedi is used as the default fallback if Pylance is not available, so errors from jedi may be arising suddenly because of a problem with Pylance.

For those of us who still want linting and intellisense who were perfectly happy with pylance and pylint, the docs [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance) say to set that as your language server like:

```
"python.languageServer": "Pylance"
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same exact issue, and it was all of a sudden. It was working just fine when I had used it earlier. A couple of hours later when I had opened the same python project files I had used earlier, I got those builtins errors and Jedi syntax errors as I was typing my code (I couldn't even finish typing my code blocks and I'd still have this issue). Plus, I had this yellow lightbulb beside my code which has never been there before. I had even tried uninstalling and reinstalling everything but no luck. Then I finally found Sourya's answer which had helped me. After setting  "python.languageServer": "None" , it all works fine.

Comment: Yeah, it worked for me as well. I'm curious as to why it works.

Comment: Given there is this post here, I am more curious on why jedi even started in the first place (happened to me as well). I've never touched anything about jedi on vscode, it never started at all before, and suddenly it starts out of nowhere.