# VScode Jedi linting

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, jedi

I would like to stop jedi linting in vscode not by disabling the language server like in this post [Disable Jedi linting for Python in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66935418/disable-jedi-linting-for-python-in-visual-studio-code), if i do this most of the features of that server are gone, like knowing which function you are in, and going to a specific function, and seeing the definition of the function when hover.

I just want the linting to stop while i am typing, or disabling the linting, but with all the other features available. How can I do that?

I am on linux, vscode from the AUR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to put in $HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json ?

```
{
    "python.jediEnabled": false
}
```